# JavaScript like Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout

Tags: javascript, graph

I have an hierarchical data structure and I'd like to render it like Microsoft's Automatic Graph Layout renders this kind of data.

[Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUUkD.png)

Each of my node includes complex HTML to be rendered, not a simple string or image.

The features I need:

- Input: Nodes and Edges (links between the nodes)
- Render on any container I'll point it to

That's it for now, really simple, just plain simple rendering.

A commercial solution (like yFiles which I've already found out about) is possible.